# How are C++ casts implemented?

Tags: c++, casting

The C++ casts `static_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` have a template-like syntax, e.g.

```
long foo = 3; 
int bar = static_cast<int>(foo);
```

I've looked in the Standard, and it says that casts are expressions, not template functions as I thought.

This left me wondering: under the hood, are these casts just templates with privileged status, or are they keywords that happen to borrow the template syntax?

Comment: "*under the hood, are these casts just templates with privileged status, or are they keywords that happen to borrow the template syntax?*" The latter.

Comment: What does it matter? Either find a way to distinguish the two ways and test for yourself or don't touch compiler internals - they should and are opaque to you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> are they keywords that happen to borrow the template syntax?

This. Casts are implemented differently depending on the context they are used in – in general, they **cannot** be implemented as functions. For instance, `static_cast` is sometimes only a compile-time operation, no code is emitted for it. But other times (in particular when invoking constructors, casting in a type hierarchy or converting between layout-incompatible primitive types) it requires a runtime operation.

That said, you can implement your own functions that *resemble* the standard cast syntax (`boost::lexical_cast` does that).